# Speed up loading when the drop down list is long

Tags: html

I am making a drop down list with html ul li. And the list length is over 500. The list data is loaded on `window.onload`. The height of the ul is fixed (300px). When pulling down the drop down list, the list is blank at first and the data will be loaded in quite a few seconds. The question is how to avoid the loading time.

Comment: you mean "how to speed up the loading of the list", right?

Comment: Or, on the contrary, do you mean "disable the drop-down untill ready"?

Comment: Your problem is bulk data.. 
when you make dropdown DOM not handle this bulk data and take time.

Then you need to use pagination.
mean not call all data at a time. Use OnScrollDown() event call data and call data on 100 limits

Comment: Yes, I want to speed up the loading of the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use paging with some plugin like https://select2.github.io/.

It's a jQuery plugin which provide autocomplete UI with configurable source. You can find many use-case examples here https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data.

The data will be loaded by small chunks (pages) and delay will be a lot shorter.

Comment: Yes. Select2 is a good choice, which provides filtering. But when the list contains 500+ items, it will be slow. I'd prefer to disable the dropdown before data is available.

Comment: @stanleyxu2005 I am suggesting to not load 500+ items at a time. Instead load by pages. You can find how to implement ajax paging with select2 here https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax

Comment: Thanks for introducing select2 to me. It works like a charm. And to my surprise, the tagging feature is awesome.